# Callback function is not called only once in Service using $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I'm trying to create a service similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412070/angularjs-how-to-get-data-from-a-polling-service-to-a-controller/32412137#32412137) example. My code is the following:

```
app.service('Poller', function ($q, $http, $timeout) {

var notification = {};
notification.poll = function (callback, error) {
    return $http.get('https://someapi.com').then(function (response) {
        if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
            if (callback){
                callback(response.data);
                console.log('tick');
            }
        } else {
            if (error) {
                error(response.data);
            }
        }
        $timeout(notification.poll, 10000);
    });
}

notification.poll();

return notification;
});
```

And I try to use it in my controller like this:

```
Poller.poll(
    function(jsonAPI) { 
        console.log(jsonAPI);
    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    }
);
```

The data are being fetched correctly but there seems to be two problems.

1. The callback function is called only once and not according to the $timeout. I added the conditionals in the service for callback end error because without them it throws an error `callback is not a function`. When I refresh or change the view the callback function is again called.
2. The $timeout seems to be triggered twice every 10 seconds and not once.

Comment: Why do you call notification.poll() without arguments?

Comment: Aren't the arguments the two functions I put in? By the way your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$timeout(function () {
    notification.poll(callback, error);
}, 10000);
```

instead of

```
$timeout(notification.poll, 10000);
```